# mysql query: search in string position

Tags: mysql, sql, select

We have a table which contains `card_no` information. containing data like:

```
-----------------------------------------
| id [int(11)] | card_no [varchar(16)]  |
-----------------------------------------
| 1            | 0124578965874563       |
| 2            | 1245789658478596       |
| 3            | 8471452369587458       |
-----------------------------------------
```

Now we need a query to find card number(s) which contains **7** in **6th** position. Or which contains **4** in **2nd** position.

This is actually needed when we printed card numbers and find some numbers unreadable. so we need to identify the card with rest of  the numbers. For example we have data like:

```
1245_896584_8596
```

Now we need to identify the card with this data.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function [**`SUBSTRING`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

```sql
SELECT id, card_no
FROM mytable
WHERE SUBSTRING(card_no, 6, 1) = '7' OR SUBSTRING(card_no, 2, 1) = '4'
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8b9c/1)

Comment: Thanks. This solutions looks good. except I need *AND* condition here.

Comment: @Chayan - But your explanation says *which contains 7 in 6th position. **Or** which contains 4 in 2nd position.*

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`SUBSTR`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) string function

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE SUBSTR(card_no,2,1) = 4 
   OR SUBSTR(card_no,6,1) = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like in where clause and wildcard for exactly one symbol _
Something like

```
select * from table where card_no like '_____7℅'
```